# Credentials for reactivesearch in Elasticsearch 8.x

Tags: vue.js, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

I want to use reactivesearch without any [appbase.io](https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/vue/overview/QuickStart/), but with a self-hosted dockerized Elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch 8.x seems to have a new concept of authorization.
I've installed ES and Kibana via docker regarding this [security measures](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-dev-mode). Then, I created an [API Key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-create-api-key.html#security-api-create-api-key-example). I'm having no problems calling ES API with curl or Postman now, great!

But, regarding these [reactivesearch docs](https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/native/overview/ReactiveBase/#usage), connecting my VueJS ReactiveSearch App directly with ES is done with these lines:

```js
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <reactive-base
            url="https://localhost:9200"
            app="data1"
            credentials="Authorization:ApiKey <Hashed API Key>"
            enableAppbase="false"
        >
            <h1>Hello from ReactiveBase </h1>
        </reactive-base>
    </div>
</template>
```

**url** should be my ES Cluster URL
**app** should be the index
**credentials** is unclear to me

As you see, I tried to put the API Authrorization in there. The documentation seems to suggest, that it should be "username:password". The app itself renders nothing and returns a blank page. So, no debugging possible.

Any ideas how to authorize ReactiveBase against a self-hosted docker ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. What I worked out was that the credentials prop in the `<ReactiveBase>` component is not needed, and to manually set the Authorization in the headers prop:

```
headers={{
          Authorization: "Bearer private-asdasdfadfasdf123123"
}}
```

Also, it looks like you may have `<reactive-base>` incorrectly defined. What I have is `<ReactiveBase>`.

Ref: https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/v3/overview/reactivebase/